# Remove all trailing characters after an alpha character is found in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search a cell and if that cell contains an alpha character I want to remove both the first alpha character and any trailing alphanumeric characters as well.  Below is code for how I can do it if I know the specific trailing character string but I need a way for it to be a wildcard version that doesn't rely on knowing the string.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A192,2)="v3", LEFT(A192,LEN(A192)-2),)
```

The above code will only work if the original cell ends with v3

```
Original      Expected
300342        300342
3003743       3003743
3000483a      3000483
3004375v2     3004375
3004375v3     3004375
3124275IE08   3124275
3124275IE11   3124275
321251b       321251
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(--LEFT(A2,MIN(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2)))))-1),A2)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOk]SW.png

Comment: I just realized I forgot an additional cell format.  The formula would need to strip the KBZ_KB from the beginning of any cell that starts with it.

    KBZ_KB3018238

Comment: That is a new question @Keith

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another solution with the same result:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,1,-1+MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A2))),1)),0)),A2)
```

this is an array formula and you need to confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

[image: Array formula]

cheers!
robrados